Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem 6
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I have a problem understanding the exercise instructions. This time is one on page 108, specifically the number 20. The problem says:


From the endpoints of the base of a triangle, let altitudes fall on the opposite
sides. Prove that the sum of the rectangles contained by the sides and their lower
segments are equal to the square on the base.


I made the next diagram, but I don't know what lower segments is talking about or even how to construct such rectangles exactly. I don't know if I'm right.

I construct the triangle $△DEF$ and plot the altitudes $\overline{DG}$ and $\overline{FI}$. Next, I construct the rectangles $⊡DGFH$ and $⊡FIDJ$.
I will be grateful if you could help me, and sorry if my English is bad.

Perhaps those are the rectangles DJFI and FGDH.

There is, fyi, an answer key to this text written by the authors son. It’s free if you search for John Casey Euclid you will find it in Google books scanned from some library. It too was very terse with few diagrams but it may help you decipher things if you find it.

Thanks! I check the altitudes of the triangles with Geogebra, by the fact that $2△DGF=\overline{DF}\overline{IM}$ (For some point $M$ such that $\overline{IM}⊥\overline{DF})$ and $2△DIF=\overline{DF}\overline{GN}$ (For some point $N$ such that $\overline{IN}⊥\overline{DF})$. Adding the areas, we get $\overline{DF}*(\overline{GN}+\overline{IN})$, so $\overline{GN}+\overline{IN}=\overline{DF}$, but cheking with Geogebra $\overline{GN}+\overline{IN}≠\overline{DF}$

Sorry, I read Ethan's suggestion carelessly, that's not the pair of rectangles in question - the question is asking: show $DEDI+FEFG=DF^2$

Thank you! I already know how to solve the problem
